Error with dpkg - Screen turns black after attempting to run dpkg --configure -a
I'm having an issue with dpkg that started two days ago when trying to run apt upgrade. I'm getting the following error message:
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

When I try to run sudo dpkg --configure -a, I see a message about initframes, but the screen turns black immediately afterward. My computer stays on, but I'm not sure if it's just the graphical interface that crashes or something else. I've encountered a similar issue before due to Nvidia drivers, but this time I'm unsure.
Here are the steps I've already tried to resolve the issue:

Ran sudo apt update -f to fix pending installations, but I still get the dpkg execution error.
Tried apt remove, autoremove, and purge—same issue with dpkg.
Recreated the dpkg file using the following commands:
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo sh -c 'for i in /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages; do dpkg --merge-avail "$i"; done'

After this, I ran apt update and then apt upgrade, but the same error occurred.

The last thing I installed before this issue was Podman and Podman Desktop. I noticed that Podman Desktop stopped showing my containers and images, and the interface freezes after a few seconds. I haven’t been able to uninstall it because apt commands aren't working.
I’ve also tried running the commands in a TTY session, but the same black screen issue happens.

Specs:

Last installed packages: Podman, Podman Desktop


I've searched online and consulted ChatGPT, but I haven't found a solution that works. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

It's very hard to make any suggestions from here ... do you have a second machine that you could use to ssh into the broken one and try to resolve the apt issues from there? Have you tried booting into rescue mode and checked whether this also happens from there?

Thank you so much, I hadn't thought about connecting via SSH. It worked perfectly, you saved me from a big hassle; I didn't want to have to reinstall my system, haha.

¡qué bueno! So you successfully resolved the issue via ssh?

That's right, I connected via SSH from another computer and ran the command dpkg --configure -a, and that resolved the issues with the black screen, allowing me to see what I was doing. The command executed correctly, and I tried to perform the upgrade again, and it worked normally.

Awesome :) ... I'm very glad to hear that that worked out.
